# React build own components

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, redux

Sometimes I need some special UI component e.g multiple range slider, but I don't like using third party libraries, so usually I create component on my own. Over time I absolute stop using  form tag, instead of that, I use just div and instead of onSubmit use just onClick, which call function, which return data from redux (also use my own redux form implementation). For example:

```
<div>
  <div className="form-title">Some random Form</div>
  <div className="form-body">
    <Input 
      type="text" 
      label="Name: *" 
      form="random_form" 
      name="name" 
    />
  </div>
  <div className="form-footer">
    <Button onClick={()=> handleSubmit()}>Save</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const form = getForm("random_form")
}
```

In this case I use component Input, which  return normal html input (). But now I thinking that i will create some other pseudo form component, which will be build from some span and div. And my question - Is okay, when I don't use form tag and create own form component, which haven't default html equivalent.

Comment: it is okay, also you can add keypress handlers for accessibility

Comment: It's ok to implement custom form component.. but you will lose a built-in onSubmit event when user press Enter after input. But anyway this can be implemented bespoke also and e.preventDefault() is kinda annoying. The thing about custom component built by yourself is you have to maintain it that's why ppl tend to go for 3rd prty libraries.

Comment: I guess you don't believe in semantic HTML or have accessibility concerns. Sure, you're free to use whatever HTML elements suits your needs. Pure HTML elements exist for a reason though. What do you have against `form`?

Comment: @DrewReese Honestly when I create my own redux form implementation, I don't figure out how it use with onSubmit, so I just moved on. But now that I'm back to it, I wonder if I missed something, which could then cause problems in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of accessibility issues, it's generally preferable to have a form tag if you're making a form, but as other people mentioned, it's not required.

You do lose some functionality if you don't have a form tag. For example, if you had an input with `required`, it would get validated when the form is submitted, but since there is no form, it's not validated automatically. One of the more subtle issues I've encountered is that browsers might not save your input for autocompletion if no submit event happens.